# mat-form-field outlined hover effect when invalid

Tags: angular, sass, hover, mat-form-field, mat-error

I'm trying to change the color of the background, of a mat-form-field outlined when I have the mouse hover.

```
.mat-form-field.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-outline-thick {
   // HOVER EFFECT
   background-color: $dark-blue-200;
}
```

The code above works well, when the form control is valid
But when, its invalid, I tried:

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid.mat-form-field-invalid
  .mat-form-field-outline-thick {
  // HOVER EFFECT
  background-color: $error-color-200;
}
```

And that changes the color permanently. Not only when I have the mouse hover.
Help please.
Thanks, David

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `:hover` CSS pseudo class to apply styles if you want them to only appear when the mouse hovers over it.
For reference, you can tweak the below CSS classes, but I think they should work

```
.mat-form-field-appearance-outline .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
    // When form is valid
    background-color: limegreen !important;
 }

.mat-form-field-appearance-outline.mat-form-field-invalid .mat-form-field-flex:hover .mat-form-field-outline {
    // When form is invalid
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

As you can see the styles will only apply due to `.mat-form-field-flex:hover`